# Highlight if cell equals value in another tab

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

What would be the custom formula to highlight a cell in Column K of Sheet 1 if it matches a cell in column K of Sheet 2? I also do not want it to include blank cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "a" cell I am assuming any cell (rather than a specific one) so please try selecting ColumnK in Sheet 1, Format > Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=match(K1,indirect("Sheet 2!K:K"),0)>0
```

with formatting of your choice. *Range:* should show `K:K`.